# How to pass a 2-D array from one thread to another thread in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

1. So I am using a bean shell post processor and towards the end I am storing the result in a 2-D array. Result is stored this way.

testArray[0][0] = "1"

testArray[0][1] = "Test"

testArray[1][0] = "2"

testArray[1][1] = "STG"

2. My requirement is that I need to pass this 2-D array to the next thread. How am I supposed to proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all [since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating to Groovy.

Coming back to your question just use `props` shorthand like:

- In first thread:

  ```
   props.put("testArray", testArray);
  ```
- in the other thread:

  ```
   testArray = props.get("testArray");
  ```

you might also want to add the current thread number as the prefix/postfix so different threads could have different arrays with separate values like:

```
props.put("testArray_" + ctx.getThreadNum(), testArray);
```

where `ctx` stand for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) class instance

More information on these `ctx`, `props` and other JMeter API shortcuts available for JSR223 Test elements: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried what you suggested :

1. In Thread 1, I added the following in a bean shell post processor.
   
      props.put("testArray", testArray);

2. In Thread 2, I added the following

    testArray = props.get("testArray");

3. Then I tried printing the result using 

   log.info(testArray)

On doing so I got null result.

Comment: You need to provide sufficient delay for the second thread to pick the value. You may introduce a delay with a constant timer.  `log.info("testArray ==>>>" + testArray.toString())` will display the content of the array in the log viewer.